# Summer of Space

Tags: discussion, topic-of-week

There are 3 large potentially helpful sources of questions that are going on right now. I suggest we take as much advantage of them as possible, to see if we can get this site promoted to the next level. We have already seen some great questions on these subjects, I suggest we continue to exploit them. The 3 events are:

1. New Horizon's flyby of Pluto (Pretty much when I'm writing this!)
2. The TV series "The Astronaut Wives Club"
3. The upcoming movie "The Martian".

All of these have some excellent potential for questions. Let's call this a topic of the month of July. Good luck!

Comment: I really should watch that sometime...

Comment: Should there be a tag for questions inspired by fiction? Or would that be a meta-tag?

Comment: It would not be a meta tag, and is an interesting question. Still, I wouldn't create one, as it doesn't seem like it would be that useful.